# Update the UI when app is loaded with data from shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have managed to persist my data using shared preferences. Upon loading the app (After it is closed),
the data is loaded correctly in the background, but the UI does not update upon start.

The default UI is shown until the user taps on a date.
Other than that the tick marks for the dates with given weight also don't show up.

I have no idea what to do about it.
Here is a demo of what the issue is:

[UI not updating in accordance with the stored data (shared preferences)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svlra.gif)

```
class UserWeight {
  int id;
  final String weight;
  double totalWeight = 0.0;
  final String date;
  String jsonString;
  var listOfWeights = [];

  UserWeight({this.weight, this.date});

  void addWeight(String dt, String wt) {}

  void removeWeight(String dt) {}
  }

  String getWeight(String dt) {
    if (listOfWeights != null) {
      for (var v in listOfWeights) {
        if (v.containsKey('date')) {
          if (v['date'] == dt) {
            return double.parse(v['weight']).toString();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return kNoWeightText; // If there is no weight for given date
  }

  String serialize() {
    jsonString = jsonEncode(listOfWeights);
    return jsonString;
  }

  read() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // var b = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(jsonDecode(jsonString));
    List<dynamic> s = jsonDecode(prefs.getString('listOfWeights') ?? []);
    listOfWeights = s;
    print("====START OF DECODE===");
    print(listOfWeights);
    for (var v in listOfWeights) {
      print(v);
    }
    print("====END OF DECODE===");
  }

  saveData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('listOfWeights', serialize());
  }
}
```

HomePage() is the first thing that loaded after main.dart

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
   // Other variables;
   UserWeight uw = new UserWeight();

   @override
   void initState() {
       uw.read();
   }
   void dispose() {}
   .....
   // this is called by builder:CalendarBuilders() of the TableCalendar() widget.
   Widget _buildEventsMarker(DateTime date, List events) {
    
    // this creates the tick marks... or it is supposed to do so.
    // events parameter is not used
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      width: 25.0,
      height: 25.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Icon(
          uw.getWeight(date.toString()) != kNoWeightText ? Icons.check : null,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please suggest any methods, or if provider package is required, then tell in which places it is to be used in this code.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you calling read() method ??

Comment: in the initState(){}

Comment: Are you doing a setState() after that ?

Comment: No.
It gives setState() called during build error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, this might work:

```
      class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
        // Other variables;
        UserWeight uw = new UserWeight();

        @override
        void initState() {
          getData();
        }

        getData() async{
          await uw.read();
          if(mounted){
            setState(() {});
          }
        }
        Widget _buildEventsMarker(DateTime date, List events) {
          
          // this creates the tick marks... or it is supposed to do so.
          // events parameter is not used
          return AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            width: 25.0,
            height: 25.0,
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                uw.getWeight(date.toString()) != kNoWeightText ? Icons.check : 
                                 null,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
```

Comment: Doesn't update the UI upon starting, but the values are loaded in the background (Checked using console).

Comment: It won't be loaded as soon as you start the app, it will take some time to load, as it is async, then your UI should reflect the changes.

Comment: Sorry but,I did what you told, but the UI doesn't update, no green ticks appear.

Comment: @DoomLord were you able to find the answer. im having the same issue

Comment: @AtharvSharma While I have solved the problem to some extent and completed that app. It has not been maintained for a long time. Anyways the code for the complete app is available on my GitHub profile : [link](https://github.com/abhishek7997/weight-tracker)

So, try to find the differences, its been untouched for so long that I can't help you much.
It was my first app that I attempted to build completely on my own without relying on tutorial (course) videos. So, its very bad at the moment.